# INSERT INTO or UPDATE in case of condition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, cursor, insert-into

I am facing a problem at the moment, and I would like a quick solution for this.

I already found another answers about this issue but none had helped, I had read about INSERT INTO and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but I think it doesn't really help me.

So the thing is, I have some Migrations enabled that Add new columns to existing tables, the thing is that the existing records on table prior to Migration get records with empty values even on existing columns (because I am changing the order of the columns on the new table migrated)

I am doing a SP that it's purpose is to fill the new Table migrated, according to Inserts or Updates.

- I want to insert new records always except in the case that I found an existing record on the table with empty columns (column Id - primary key - is filled)

The "pseudo code" *(mixing sql tables knowledge and c# syntax)* would be something like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(Record item in importing_data_table)
{

     if(i < tableMigrated.Length && tableMigrated[i].Column IS NULL)
     {
          UPDATE tableMigrated[i] SET Column = item.Column
     }
     else
     {
          INSERT INTO item 
     }

     i++;
}
```

**NOTE: Deleting all the rows** from the tableMigrated before inserting is not **possible**, because there are foreign keys to that table. I got the following error trying that approach: 
- The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_blabla.Testing_testingTest.tableMigrated_Id".

**NOTE2**: Maybe my only option is using Cursors?

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: I knew somebody was going to ask this question.  I solved it for myself this week.  Update returns an integer indicating number of rows affected.  So if Update return zero then I insert the data.  You can't insert if the Primary Key value already exists in the database.  So first try update and if it returns zero rows affected then use Insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Stored Procedure, use the Merge Statement.  Merge provides the functionality to INSERT based on your insert condition, otherwise UPDATE.  Here is an example

```
MERGE dbo.FactBuyingHabits AS Target
USING (SELECT CustomerID, ProductID, PurchaseDate FROM dbo.Purchases) AS Source
ON (Target.ProductID = Source.ProductID AND Target.CustomerID = Source.CustomerID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.LastPurchaseDate = Source.PurchaseDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (CustomerID, ProductID, LastPurchaseDate)
    VALUES (Source.CustomerID, Source.ProductID, Source.PurchaseDate)
```

Take a look at [Technet - Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data by Using MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am getting an error, can't find the problem, sometimes SQL just drives me crazy god damn it... the error shown most of the times don't help at all ! Here is my current code, http://pastebin.com/R0uByLqv

Comment: Finnaly got it working, it seems I really need to use "Target" as the last word on Merge statement (first line), I tough that it could be any Alias for the target database, it seems now =/

Comment: Actually I can use the word "Target" with any alias for the table, my problem was a replace all that also changed "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN" to "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY MYTABLEALIAS THEN", changing MYTABLEALIAS to TARGET it started working perfectly, thank you so much for your answer ! :)

Comment: great, nice one TiagoM